# Module Redirect - fresh install not working

Tags: 7, redirection

I have installed **Redirect** module on my site and created a redirect from one url to another, but it's not working at all. **404 error page** is always returned.

I tried to reinstall it, reenable it, tried the dev version of module, but nothing changed. 
There are no errors or warnings in site log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the page you redirect to accessible when you try to surf it manually? Have you checked if the behaviour is the same when logged in as admin and as anonymous user? Perhaps you have special rewrite rules declared in your .htaccess file?

Comment: did you checked that the page is there in your site for example: if youhave url -example.com/test test by accessing the url manually if its working we have to go for some other work around

Comment: The behaviour is the same for all users and the page is accessible. I tried to redirect to external urls as well, but it's not working as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue with a specific module and should be directed to the relevant issue queue.